# awakeFromNib does not change UILabel property

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and I lay out the views like this in a xib file:

[image: one]

And my custom `UICollectionViewCell` is set up as follows:

```
class DurationDayCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var banner: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfHours: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var unitHrs: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dayOfWeek: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var hourContainer: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.unitHrs.sizeToFit()
        self.dayOfWeek.sizeToFit()
        self.numberOfHours.sizeToFit()
}
```

However when I run it, the collection view looks like this:

[image: two]

Why doesn't the code I put in `awakeFromNib` change anything? I guess I just don't really understand how it works, can someone elucidate it please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you expecting to obtain by calling sizeToFit?

Comment: so the text of the hour label will fit into the label?

Comment: does the cell size vary? or is it always the same?

Comment: @marosoaie the cell size vary, it's another problem i ran into using nib -- i can make the UIViews to `aspect fill` but the labels inside them are hard to adjust, as you can see the days labels are not proportional to blue view like in the nib.

Comment: @matt well, i wasn't able to change property of the label, which is a subview of nib

Comment: If you want to display `3hrs` with `3` and `hrs` in different fonts, you don't need to use two labels, you can use a single label with an attributed string, this would make it easier. By the looks of it, your constraints aren't working properly anyway since hrs is at the top in the rendered view, instead of centered like in the nib.

Comment: Note: change color of label text doesn't work here either - had to move it to layoutSubviews!

Answer (score 0):

Your nib is using auto layout (as is clear from your screen shot showing that the views in the nib have constraints on them). `sizeToFit` has no effect on a view that is under auto layout constraints, because its size is set by the constraints.

But calling `sizeToFit` is the only thing you are doing in your `awakeFromNib`. Thus your `awakeFromNib` is pointless.

Comment: I don't know what you should have done because I have no idea what you want to do. I answered the question you asked, I think. I have no other information.

Comment: Your question was: "Why doesn't the code I put in awakeFromNib change anything?" I explained that. The label size is completely set by its constraints.